# Is it possible to build a docker image from /tmp (tmpfs)?

Tags: 18.04, docker

I was trying to build a dockerfile from /tmp, but encountered a "path not found" error. The build was successful if I use a local filesystem. So I think the only issue is the permission of `/tmp`. Since I always use /tmp as a scratch space, I feel it will be good to know a way to fix this. The docker command is generated by a software, so I prefer to use it as-is, only make changes to my settings.

```
ubuntu@machine1:/tmp/work$ docker build -t myproject project
unable to prepare context: path "project" not found
ubuntu@machine1:/tmp/work$ ls project
build.sh  Dockerfile  project.yaml
ubuntu@machine1:/tmp/work$
```

My `/tmp` is mounted on `tmpfs`, the fstab entry is:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs mode=777,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with docker 18.09 installed via snap. I am the only user of this machine, so it's OK to change the permission to be permissive.